# FFMPEG split into two frames with BGR convertion instead of RGB | OpenVino

Tags: ffmpeg, intel, openvino

[image]

I don't know why this happen because when i pass the normal frames directly, it didnot split into two frames but when i do some post-processing to count the person at 2nd person it flips into 2 frames.

I think flush called or i missed one frame in loop :/

So my question is that How can this is possible as i am directly feeding my frames ?

I used following ffmpeg command to pipe with python.

- **ffmpeg -v warning -f rawvideo -pixel_format bgr24 -video_size 768x432 -framerate 24 -i - http://0.0.0.0:3004/fac.ffm**

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have "print" or "log" in the code that send anything to the terminal as it will mess up the ffmpeg encoding.